# Is it possible to get user's permission scope with Microsoft Graph API Access Token (not application's scope)?

Tags: oauth, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I've got an AAD Application with a list of granted delegated permissions. Like:

```
Directory.AccessAsUser.All
Directory.ReadWrite.All
Group.ReadWrite.All
```

Mostly users do not have such permissions.
I'd like to hide some UI elements for them (edit group, for example)

But in response with Access token I get all scopes of application. And that information is not really useful. I want to prevent users from getting errors like *'Insufficient privileges to complete the operation'*.

Is this possible?

Comment: A single Access Token can only contain one type of scopes (Application or Delegated). So if your particular scenario requires both Application and Delegated scopes, your application will need to obtain two separate tokens. The first will represent the User and be obtained using an Authorization Cord or Implicit grant, the second will represent the application itself and be obtained using a Client Credentials grant.

Comment: @SruthiJ-MSFTIdentity, can you provide any link how I can setup auth flow to get user's token?

Comment: Please try with [auth code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow)

Comment: Hi, did you check my answer? Is it helpful?

Comment: Still in progress. I will give you response in the beginning of the next week. What I've found: looks like user's scope is getting with /authorize

Answer (score 0):

Based on the comment, you want some information about auth code flow in using Microsoft Graph.

Please refer to the official document: [Get access on behalf of a user](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0) under Microsoft Graph API.

There are 2 main steps:

[Authorization request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#authorization-request):

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&response_mode=query
&scope=offline_access%20user.read%20mail.read
&state=12345
```

You will get a `code` parameter. Use it in the second step:

[Token request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth-v2-user?context=graph%2Fapi%2F1.0&view=graph-rest-1.0#token-request):

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=user.read%20mail.read
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh    // NOTE: Only required for web apps
```

Then you will get the access token which contains Delegated permissions.

For how to implement auth code flow in code, please refer to [Microsoft Graph SDKs overview](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/sdks-overview?view=graph-rest-1.0). [Authorization code provider](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/sdks/choose-authentication-providers?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=CS#authorization-code-provider) will be helpful.